# How to post base64string data to webview with URL?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm working on payment gateway where I want to pass some data in encryption hash format with hash_hmac sha512 after that convert the output using Base64.
I have URL to post with generated base64 string data into webview.

I'm new to aba payment. I've tried to post data and it always gives error like 403 forbidden error.

I expect the way or code to post data in webview with URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post data in base64 form with url and load in webview, then you can use this code.

```
String url = "http://your_url.com";
String postData = "your_data_you_want_to_post";
your_wv.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```